# jQuery fadeTo not working on page exit

Tags: jquery, wordpress, animation, transition

I've scoured the internet for solutions for hours, but my code still doesn't work. I am creating a jQuery page transition whereby my website's main content (other than the header and footer) will fade in as a page loads, and fade out as a page exits/transitions to another page. I am using fadeTo() to change its opacity as fadeIn() and fadeOut() removes the main content, causing the footer to 'move up' the page in its place.

The problem is that my current code does not show any fading transition effect:

```
(function( $ ) {
"use strict";

$(function() {

    // Your code here
        $("#main.site-main").css('opacity', '0');
        $("#main.site-main").fadeTo(1000, 1); 

$(".nav-menu li").click(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            newLocation = this.href;

$("#main.site-main").fadeTo(1000, 0, function () {

            window.location = newLocation;

        });​


});


}(jQuery));
```

But the following code works, which only shows the main content 'fade in' as a page loads:

```
(function( $ ) {
    "use strict";

$(function() {

    // Your code here
        $("#main.site-main").css('opacity', '0');
        $("#main.site-main").fadeTo(1000, 1); 

});


}(jQuery));
```

So how can I achieve the fade in AND fade out effect for my page transition? And why isn't the top code working?

Comment: @SagarSakre: please don't use inline code spans (`like this`) to highlight words, they are only meant for code within sentences. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135113/220428) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I've done it in this way, you may adopt that code:

```
jQuery('a').click(function(event) {

    // don't exec the link loading (a href stuff) - we do it explicitly
    event.preventDefault();
    var that = jQuery(this);
    var target = jQuery(this).attr("target");
    if (jQuery.trim(target).length > 0)
    {
        window.open(that.attr("href"), target);
    }
    else
    {
        // fade out content, load next document
        jQuery('.content-style').animate({
            opacity : "0"
        }, {
            duration : 700,
            "complete" : function() {

                document.location = that.attr("href");
            }
        } // complete callback
        ); // animate properties
    }
}); // click callback
```

Comment: Thank you Axel. I tried your code, but it didn't reproduce the fade effects either. I only changed the `'a'` and `'.content-style'`. If you know why this might be though, I'd be grateful if you could share your thoughts/a solution, if possible.

Comment: to dig in to that, we need more code, i.e. the according html and JS/jQuery code of that page or an example link to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".nav-menu li").on("click", function(event) {
    $("#main.site-main").fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
        window.location = event.currentTarget.href;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @David. This worked! But there were a few glitches. I'd be very grateful if you could share some insight into why they are happening and how they could be fixed (if you know)?:

1. sometimes the pages load as 'undefined' in the address bar, and a 404 page would pop up --- 

2. the fade animation when you leave a page sometimes doesn't complete before the next page loads. I've tried speeding the fade up, but this causes the above problem to happen more often ---

Thanks again David.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of some people on this site, and trial and error, the following code does just what I want. It's a bit slow for me though, but that's a question for another day.

The code:

```
   (function( $ ) {

        "use strict";

        $(function() {

            // Your code here

    var $sitemain = $( "#main" ).find( "div.site-main" );

            $sitemain.fadeTo(200, 1); 

    $($( "#site-navigation" ).find( "a" ), $( "#masthead" ).find( "a.home-link"   )).on("click", function(event) {
    $sitemain.fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
        window.location = event.currentTarget.href;
        });
    });


    });
    }(jQuery));
```